# Calculating $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-y^{2} / 2} d y$ with a two decimal precision

Tags: numerical-methods

Consider the distribution function of the normal distribution,
$$
F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-y^{2} / 2} d y
$$
We want to calculate the $F(1.96)$ with a two decimal precision. Devise a method for doing so, and find the number of divisions needed using the Trapezoidal method.

---

$f(y)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-y^{2} / 2}$ is symmetric, so from $-\infty$ to $0$ the integral is $1/2$. So we can just calculate $\int_0^xf(y)dy$. I now want to find the $n$ such that $|E|≤ 0.01$. Observe that:

$$\max_{0\leq x\leq 1.96} |f''(y)| = |f''(0)| =\left| (0^2-1)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-0^2}{2}}\right|  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$$

So the upper bound for the error

$$E=-\frac{(b-a) h^{2}}{12} f^{\prime \prime}(\xi), \quad \xi\in(a,b)$$

is

$$|E| \leq -\frac{(1.96) h^{2}}{12} f''(0), \quad \xi\in(0,1.96)$$

I get that $n\geq 1$. Is my method correct?

Kind regards,

Comment: Dont you need to bound $f''$ insread of $f$?

Comment: typo @ArcticChar

Comment: But you did not differentiate.....

Comment: yes, I did. but didn't wrote it. haha
$$
f''(y) = (y^2-1)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}
$$ @ArcticChar

Comment: You should do a table lookup and compare with your result. Then you know if you reasoning is correct!

Comment: Maybe of interest https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sbHUHxXpvus

Comment: Could you explain how your correct numerical values and your formulas lead to your result? I get $h<0.39$ which forces $n\ge 6$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I threw my calculations out because I thought I was right. I will make them as soon as I get time (I'm studying for 5 exams, so I'm very busy )